# How to destroy host component on pressing escape key using directive in angular?

Tags: angular

Following is my implementation for destroying a popup on pressing escape.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[escapeHostDestroy]',
})

export class DestroyPopUpOnEscapeDirective {
    constructor(
      private renderer: Renderer2,
      private el: ElementRef,
      private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef
    ) {}

    @HostListener('document:keydown.escape', ['$event']) destroyHost(ev: KeyboardEvent) {
        this.renderer.destroy();
    }
  }
```

But it seems out that it is not working.

I can hide/show this pop using renderer(set style). 
But I don't want that. Instead I want to destroy the host component where the directive sits on.

How can I achieve that?

**& also one more doubt, How can I access a components methods inside a directive (so that I can trigger events from the directive itself... something like injecting the componenet in to directive)**

```
//main component.html

<app-popup *ngIf="showPopup"></app-popup>
```

```
// popup component.html
<div escapeHostDestroy>
... {%rest of popup contents here%}
</div>
```

Comment: You should handle that in the part where you show the popup/dialog. Can you post that part?

Comment: yep. did that. check out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the way you want it, it's not really possible. Better would be to use a service which controls the showing of the dialog. If you still want to use a directive, you can do it with a service like this:

```
export enum Popup {
  Main = 'main',
  Foo = 'foo',
  Bar = 'bar'
}


@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class PopupService {
  readonly popups: Partial<Record<Popup, boolean>> = {};

  isOpen(popup: Popup): boolean {
    return !!this.popups[popup];
  }

  showPopup(popup: Popup): void {
    this.popups[popup] = true;
  }

  hidePopup(popup: Popup): void {   
    this.popups[popup] = false;
  }
}
```

Which you can use in your template (after injecting the service in your parent component):

```
<app-popup *ngIf="popupService.isOpen('main')"></app-popup>
```

And you can change your directive to this. This also answers your question how to access the popup from the directive, you need to inject the `PopupComponent` in your directive, and use the `@Host()` annotation to be sure you get the right one:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[escapeHostDestroy]',
})

export class DestroyPopUpOnEscapeDirective {
  constructor(@Host() private popup: PopupComponent) {}

  @HostListener('document:keydown.escape')
  hidePopup(): void {
    this.popup.hide();
  }
}
```

and update your popup component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-popup',
  template: ``
})
export class MainPopupComponent extends PopupComponent {
  readonly popup: Popup = Popup.Main;

  constructor(popupService: PopupService) {
    super(popupService);
  }
}
```

And create an abstract popup component which your popups extends:

```
@Directive()
export abstract class PopupComponent {
  abstract readonly popup: Popup;

  protected constructor(protected popupService: PopupService) {}

  hide(): void {
    this.popupService.hidePopup(this.popup);
  }
}
```

---

There are obviously, like you know, a lot of libraries out there which can do this for you as well. Especially angular material or the angular cdk is a nice starting point for this, but if you like to keep things simple and educational, you can first try to do it yourself :). That's to say, my answer is a very simplified version on how to control the showing of dialogs.

Comment: Hi. I like this idea. @Host() private popup: PopupComponent
But how can i make it reusable for different popups? Do I need to inject all of them separately and call the methods inside them.

Comment: Is there a smart method for this.

Comment: @mex my current solution only works for one global popup object. However, it's easy-ish to extend this to a multi popup situation. I'll update my code

Comment: Ok. Please extend it. It willl be very useful.

Comment: One more help. Is there a way to bind to clientWidth throught host binding?

Comment: @mex Yes, you use `style.width.px` binding (if you want pixels): `@HostBinding('style.width.px') width: number = 300` will result in a style rule of `width: 300px` to be added to the component

Comment: Yeah. But style will be something we set. How can I read width from the element?

Comment: @mex You need to get the `ElementRef` and read the native element. Nevertheless, you will most likely run into 'expression has changed' errors. Better to check it once, and update the value by using the `ResizeOberver`

Answer (score 1):

The below may be of help given your comments and use case:

https://stackblitz.com/github/ClientsideDesign/ngx-dialog-injection-starter-pack

This is an implementation of a reusable material dialog with an injected child component (which has a form) and communication between parent and child component. As per the answer from [@poul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3106920/poul-kruijt), setting up a service to communicate when the dialog should be closed is key.

- `dialog-wrapper` is a dialog component
- `dialog-form` is an example of a dynamic component being injected into `dialog-wrapper`, with the necessary supporting services.
- `name` (Alice) is an example of arbitrary data being passed from the parent component to `dialog-form` via `dialog-wrapper`
- An object with `name` and `favouriteFood` is then passed back to the parent when the form in `dialog-form` is submitted. This also tiggers the parent component to close `dialog-wrapper`.

I've tried to keep the code as straightforward as possible so it can be easily retasked. The [dialog wrapper](https://github.com/ClientsideDesign/ngx-dialog-injection-starter-pack/blob/master/src/app/dialog-wrapper/dialog-wrapper.component.ts) itself is fairly simple; most of the heavy lifting is in the [injected component](https://github.com/ClientsideDesign/ngx-dialog-injection-starter-pack/blob/master/src/app/dialog-form/dialog-form.component.ts) and the [parent component](https://github.com/ClientsideDesign/ngx-dialog-injection-starter-pack/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts).

As per your original post, the dialog is closed and the child components destroyed when you press `escape`.

The full code can be reviewed on https://github.com/ClientsideDesign/ngx-dialog-injection-starter-pack.